# Given that $\pi<x<3\pi/2$, then the expression $\sqrt{4\sin^4x+\sin^22x}+4\cos^2[\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}]$ is

Tags: trigonometry

The left side of the expression reduces to $2\sin x$ and the right side reduces $2+2\sin x$

Their addition gives $2+4\sin x$ . The correct answer is 2

I realize that this has got to do with the fact that $\pi<x<3\pi/2$ , in which case $\sin x$ will be -ve.

But then the expression should be $2-4\sin x$.  How does it end up being 2?

Comment: Where are the two sides and how $$\alpha$$ is related to $$x?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee it was a typo, my bad. Also the two sides are the two terms of the expression. I should have mentioned that. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{4\sin^4x+\sin^2(2x)}+4\cos^2\left(\frac\pi4-\frac x2\right)$$
$$=\sqrt{4\sin^4x+4\sin^2x\cdot\cos^2x}+2\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)+1\right)$$
$$=2\vert \sin x \vert \sqrt{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}+2\sin x+2$$
$$=-2\sin x+2\sin x+2=2$$

Comment: Does it have to be $|\sin x|$? Why?

Comment: From square root we get -2Sinx and from Cos part we get 2Sinx

Comment: Always $\sqrt{x^2}=\vert x \vert $

Comment: But is it necessary to write $|\sin x|$ as $-\sin x$? Why can’t we write the positive term?

Comment: Since x is in 3rd qudarant where Sinx is -ve but whole of the Value is +ve. Hence $\vert Sinx \vert=-Sinx$

Comment: Writing $|\sin x|=-\sin x$ feels a little wrong

Comment: In 3rd qudarant is Sinx +ve or -ve, and remember modulus is always +ve.

Comment: So basically, what you intend to say is that $-\sin x$ is a positive quantity, since, $\sin x$ is negative in the given conditions

Comment: Absolutely correct